# How to resolve "invalid entry size" Java error from the R package xlsx

Tags: java, r, excel

I am using the `R` package `xlsx` to extract cell color information from a large number of XLSX spreadsheets. I am trying to load the workbook using this code:

```
xl_path <- "<path>/<to>/file.xlsx"
wb <- xlsx::loadWorkbook(xl_path)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 1178 bytes)
```

The XLSX file was generated by someone else, but I can open it with `Excel` or load to `R` with `readxl` without any issues.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that error, but ... if you can read using `readxl`, is there a reason to stay with the java-encumbered `xlsx` package?

Comment: I am using the `R` package `xlsx` to extract cell color information

Comment: ahh, okay ... good reason, I guess

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the `XLSX` were not generated with consistent names for sections, but they were generated with consistent colored dividers between sections.